# Database to track visits vs dynamic targets

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm designing a new database to track accounts achieved visits vs monthly targets. The final report shall be requested by start/end dates and one account to show the months inbetween with monthly target and sum of visits.
The complication started when I knew the number of accounts is more than 10 thousands and the targets should be changed monthly or not for the only changed accounts targets(i.e each target will have start and end date. if no end date then the target is always valid). At this point I lost and I need help

For simplicity I will assume I have table with dates periods and simplest situation as follow

```
accounts
+----+---------+ 
|id  | name    |
+----+---------+ 
| 1  | account1|
| 2  | account2|
+----+---------+

targets
+---+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
|id | account_id | start_date | end_date  | monthly_target |
+---+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+
|1  | 1          | 1-1-2016   | 31-1-2016 | 5              |
|2  | 1          | 1-2-2016   | 31-5-2016 | 4              |
|3  | 1          | 1-7-2016   | null      | 7              |
|4  | 2          | 1-1-2016   | null      | 10             |
+---+------------+------------+-----------+----------------+

visits
+---+-----------+------------+
|id | date      | account_id |
+----------------------------+
|1  | 15-1-2016 | 1          |
|2  | 20-1-2016 | 1          |
|3  | 10-5-2016 | 1          |
|3  | 20-5-2016 | 1          |
|4  | 20-5-2016 | 2          |
+---+-----------+------------+

calendar (Optional)
----------+----------+
|start    | end      |
----------+----------+
|1-1-2016 | 31-1-2016|
|1-2-2016 | 29-2-2016|
|1-3-2016 | 31-3-2016|
|1-4-2016 | 30-4-2016|
|1-5-2016 | 31-5-2016|
|1-6-2016 | 30-6-2016|
|1-7-2016 | 31-7-2016|
|1-8-2016 | 31-7-2016|
+---------+----------+
```

Expected report for account1 coverage from 1-4-2016 to 31-7-2016

```
+---------+-----------+--------+----+
|start    | end       | target | sum|
+---------+-----------+--------+----+
|1-4-2016 | 30-4-2016 | 4      | 0  |
|1-5-2016 | 31-5-2016 | 4      | 2  |
|1-6-2016 | 30-6-2016 | 0      | 0  |
|1-7-2016 | 31-7-2016 | 7      | 0  |
+---------+-----------+--------+----+
```

I can accept changing my initial design if it causes problems  but assuming the design of targets table is the most practical design for system admin.

I need help in SQL needed to generate the final report.

Comment: How does your actual data shown relate to the Expected Report shown?

Comment: Oh I see your targets have a range to make it easier for the admin side (harder for the programmer side). No wonder you just stopped after the design !

Comment: The visits table is filled by data coming by representatives and targets data filled by admin and supervisors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the range of dates in `targets` to have an explicit end date even if that means end of year. This way, avoiding the null, the sql could range ok. It also uses the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) Standard for dates. And it is implemented in a Stored Proc that takes 3 parameters: account_id, start and end date.

Alias `v`, the derived table, prevents double counts versus a flat out `LEFT JOIN` against the visits table. For instance, that 2 would be an errant 7 without that strategy. So it used the [`LAST_DAY()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) function.

Schema:

```
create table accounts
(   id int not null,
    name varchar(100) not null
);
insert accounts values
(1,'account1'),
(2,'account2');

-- drop table targets;
create table targets
(   id int not null,
    account_id int not null,
    start_date date not null,
    end_date date not null,
    monthly_target int not null
);
-- truncate targets;
insert targets values
(1,1,'2016-01-01','2016-01-31',5),
(2,1,'2016-02-01','2016-05-31',4),
(3,1,'2016-07-01','2016-12-31',7),
(4,2,'2016-01-01','2016-12-31',10);

create table visits
(   id int not null,
    date date not null,
    account_id int not null
);
-- truncate visits;
insert visits values
(1,'2016-01-15',1),
(2,'2016-01-20',1),
(3,'2016-05-10',1),
(4,'2016-05-20',1),
(5,'2016-05-20',2);


create table calendar
(   start date not null,
    end date not null
);
insert calendar values
('2016-01-01','2016-01-31'),
('2016-02-01','2016-02-29'),
('2016-03-01','2016-03-31'),
('2016-04-01','2016-04-30'),
('2016-05-01','2016-05-31'),
('2016-06-01','2016-06-30'),
('2016-07-01','2016-07-31'),
('2016-08-01','2016-08-31'),
('2016-09-01','2016-09-30'),
('2016-10-01','2016-10-31'),
('2016-11-01','2016-11-30'),
('2016-12-01','2016-12-31');
```

Stored Proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS uspGetRangeReport007;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE uspGetRangeReport007
(   p_account_id INT,
    p_start DATE,
    p_end DATE
)
BEGIN
    SELECT c.start,c.end,
    IFNULL(t.monthly_target,0) as target,
    -- IFNULL(sum(v.id),0) as visits
    IFNULL(v.theCount,0) as visits
    FROM calendar c
    LEFT JOIN targets t
    ON account_id=p_account_id 
    AND c.start BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
    AND c.end BETWEEN t.start_date AND t.end_date
    LEFT JOIN 
    (   SELECT LAST_DAY(date) as lastDayOfMonth,
        count(id) as theCount
        FROM VISITS
        WHERE account_id=p_account_id
        GROUP BY LAST_DAY(date)
    ) v
    ON v.lastDayOfMonth BETWEEN c.start AND c.end
    WHERE c.start BETWEEN p_start AND p_end
    AND c.end BETWEEN p_start AND p_end
    GROUP BY c.start,c.end,t.monthly_target
    ORDER BY c.start;
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
call uspGetRangeReport007(1,'2016-04-01','2016-07-31'); 
+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| start      | end        | target | visits |
+------------+------------+--------+--------+
| 2016-04-01 | 2016-04-30 |      4 |      0 |
| 2016-05-01 | 2016-05-31 |      4 |      2 |
| 2016-06-01 | 2016-06-30 |      0 |      0 |
| 2016-07-01 | 2016-07-31 |      7 |      0 |
+------------+------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thank you for your fantastic reply. Shall i understand from your reply you agree on the design idea.

Comment: give me 20 minutes, finishing up another answer

Comment: Yes. Despite the little that I know of your business, there is not much risk in saying so. I would not have the `end_date` nullable mainly due to various queries not working too easily as mentioned. I love helper tables for left joins so that is nice. Also note that I went 1,2,3,4,5 in my id's in one table, assuming you had a typo. I didn't think that was relevant to the question or some `id` thing I had to inquire about. Also note that there was no discussion about index choices

Comment: I would definitely have some composite indexes on acct id and date or dates, depending on the table. In fact we were just showing stub tables without any PK's. So clean all that up. PK the id's. If you need help with the other indexes, just ask, like the composites.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  c.start,
        c.end,
        t.monthly_target AS target, 
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
            FROM  visits
            WHERE  `date` BETWEEN c.start AND c.end 
              AND  account_id = ?   -- Specify '1'
        ) AS `sum`            -- Correlated subquery for counting visits
    FROM  Calendar AS c
    JOIN  targets AS t  ON c.start_date >= t.start_date
                     AND ( t.end_date IS NULL
                        OR c.start_date < t.end_date )
    WHERE  c.start >= ?       -- Specify date range
      AND  c.end   <= ?
```

Comment: what is v in the where clause?

Comment: Hmmm.. smells like a typo.  Or, rather, I failed to put `account_id` next to `visits`.  See the edit.